# Trouble adding new object to arraylist

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

I am making a survey type program that collects data and puts that data into an ArrayList. The ArrayList is a list for *Match* objects. It is supposed to take the inputs from the user and put them in the ArrayList when the user presses the *Submit* button. Here is the EventHandler code

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> submitMatch = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
{
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        debug.setText("button pressed");
        matches.add(new Match(Integer.parseInt(teamNum), allianceColor, Integer.parseInt(matchNum), repositing, skyStoneBonus, 
            Integer.parseInt(autoStoneDelivered),Integer.parseInt(autoPlacing), navigation, underBar, Integer.parseInt(stonesDelivered), 
            Integer.parseInt(stonesPlaced), Integer.parseInt(skyscraperHeight), capstone, Integer.parseInt(capstoneLevel),
            foundationMoved, park, penalty, defense, rating, notes));
        debug.setText("match added");
        primaryStage.setScene(mainMenuScene);
    }
};
```

After the match is added to the ArrayList it is supposed to go to the Main Menu scene, but it never reaches that point. As for the debug label, it reaches the "button pressed" but doesn't reach the "match added".

I am new to JavaFx and new to stackOverflow, so if any additional information is need let me know!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't see the match added debug statement, it means that the previous instruction throws an exception (or that the Match constructor has an infinite loop). Read the stack trace of that exception to know what the problem is.

Comment: And assuming you don't enter a nested event loop, the infinite loop is not a possibility. Otherwise the GUI would freeze before changing the text. One thing that seems odd to me is the fact that you're not reading those input strings in the event handler. Unless you've got listeners to the input properties or some other event handlers triggered before the button click, those fields(?) won't contain the values of the inputs at the time of clicking the button. However the info provided it's impossible to identify the exact issue. Please [edit] the question and provide a [mcve].